# Formatting decimal point in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

My code has been an evolving process and the end game is to implement a UI using JOptionPane to my previous iteration. I successfully formatted an output to a 2 decimal place using String.format("Text goes here %.2f", variable) but when I try to carry this method over to my iteration of code using JOptionPane it crashes the program.

Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ass1d2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        final int N = 7;
        String taxPayerName;
        int taxPayerIncome = 0;
        double maxTax = 0.0;
        String maxTaxName = "";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to use Tax Computation System");

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {

            taxPayerName = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter tax payers name");

            taxPayerIncome =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter income for the tax payer"));

            double tax = computeTax(taxPayerIncome);

            if (taxPayerIncome > maxTax){
                maxTax = tax;
                maxTaxName = taxPayerName;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The tax that " + taxPayerName + " owes is $" + tax));
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The maximum tax is $" + maxTax) + " paid by " + maxTaxName);
    }

    private static double computeTax(int taxPayerIncome)
    {
        double tax = 0.0;

        if (taxPayerIncome < 18200)
        tax = 0;

        else if (taxPayerIncome < 37000)
        tax = (taxPayerIncome - 18200) * 0.19;

        else if (taxPayerIncome < 87000)
        tax = 3572 + (taxPayerIncome - 37000) * 0.325;

        else if (taxPayerIncome < 180000)
        tax = 19822 + (taxPayerIncome - 87000) * 0.37;

        else
        tax = 54232 + (taxPayerIncome - 180000) * 0.47;

        return tax;
    }
}
```

How do I format the two showMessageDialog to produce a two decimal floating point result? I've been scouring guides for the past hour and it's just not clicking. Very frustrating that this is the final roadblock. Thanks.

Comment: Your tax type is double, that returns value after decimal point. You may want to use BigDecimal for financial calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Well I must have done a typo in my other attempts as I have it working now. Awkward. Attached updated code with working floating point result for future reference.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ass1d2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        final int N = 3;
        String taxPayerName;
        int taxPayerIncome = 0;
        double maxTax = 0.0;
        String maxTaxName = "";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to use Tax Computation System");

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {

            taxPayerName = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter tax payers name");

            taxPayerIncome =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter income for the tax payer"));

            double tax = computeTax(taxPayerIncome);

            if (taxPayerIncome > maxTax){
                maxTax = tax;
                maxTaxName = taxPayerName;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The tax that " + taxPayerName + " owes is $" + String.format("%.2f", tax));
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The maximum tax is $" + String.format("%.2f", maxTax) + " paid by " + maxTaxName);
    }

    private static double computeTax(int taxPayerIncome)
    {
        double tax = 0.0;

        if (taxPayerIncome < 18200)
        tax = 0;

        else if (taxPayerIncome < 37000)
        tax = (taxPayerIncome - 18200) * 0.19;

        else if (taxPayerIncome < 87000)
        tax = 3572 + (taxPayerIncome - 37000) * 0.325;

        else if (taxPayerIncome < 180000)
        tax = 19822 + (taxPayerIncome - 87000) * 0.37;

        else
        tax = 54232 + (taxPayerIncome - 180000) * 0.47;

        return tax;
    }
}
```